# Apt-get update failure

Tags: apt, updates

I keep getting this error every time I run `sudo apt-get update` and also I'm getting a red notification in the top right of my computer that says my

> update information is outdated

This is the result of `update` command:

```
Fetched 132 kB in 3s (42.5 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command for 64 Bit Linux:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list"
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is because google has stopped support for chrome 32bit for linux. 
There is two solution for this problem:

1. Remove chrome and use chromium or some other browser(If your are running in a 32 bit os)
2. Add Chrome 64 bit ppa(If you are using 64 bit os)

   > sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list" "/opt/google/chrome/cron/google-chrome"

Comment: First of all, uninstalling an app and replacing it with something else, is not answer but a suggestion. Secondly, what you gave as an answer was given by @Ashu here 11 hours ago. What was your aim for repeating it?

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha I suggested the first answer because there is no other solution than that if you are using 32 bit. The second one beacuse i wanted my answer to be complete. I was not aware that part of answers should not repeat